# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket (From time to time)

Tags: mysql

I have a LAMP stack setup. Occasionally, I get the following error message when I open some page from the browser:

```
Error creating the connection!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I think the server was configured correctly. The problem happens about every two months. Every time when I reboot the Linux server, or restart mysql, the problem was gone. I want to fix this problem permanently. Can anyone give me some idea?

Much appreciated.

### EDIT

The problem occurs again and I checked the mysqld.sock file, it was not there. Do you have any idea how to fix the problem? – Ryan Jul 23 at 16:24

Comment: Please check `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` when you can't connect. Is it still exist or not. I guess it was deleted periodically by your system

Comment: @DollyAswin Thanks for your comment. I can try that when it goes down next time.

Comment: @DollyAswin The problem occurs again and I checked the mysqld.sock file, it was not there. Do you have any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: @Ryan: Did you checked if mysql server crashed for any reason? check the MySQL logs in /var/log/mysql.

Answer (score 2):

If your file `my.cnf` (usually in the `/etc/mysql/` folder) is correctly configured with

```
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

modified

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address = localhost
```

you can check if mysql is running with the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

try changing your permission to mysql folder. If you are working locally, you can try:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/run/mysqld/
```

And then restart the mysql.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry i can't find any /var/run/mysqld/ folder and show error  Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the log file getting too large and rebooting flushes it. See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-file-maintenance.html) in docs on server maintenance and logfiles. Also see discussion at [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-2). Appears to be confirmed by discussion at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/65050/can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock)

Answer (score 1):

You could try change the permission of your MySQL sock file like this:

```
chmod 777 '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

It is a test to see if whatever user mysqld is using, it will acess your mysqld.sock file. So, reboot your MySQL and change the permission of mysqld.sock. And you need to check that if your sock folder can be accessed through any mysqld process.

Answer (score -2):

If the `mysqld.sock` file doesn't exist, that is to say your config file is not correct.Check your mysql config file in `/etc/mysql/my.conf`, find the socket config just as Vanya Avchyan says.

I think the socket config is `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, but in fact your mysql process runs in other place sock file. 
I used to met that problem, the real socket file exists in `/tmp/mysqld.sock`.
So run

`sudo find / -name 'mysqld.sock'`

to find the real sock file and change `my.conf` to this real place, restart your mysql. May have work.